# Shell script - is there a faster way to write date/time per second between start and end time?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this script (which works fine) that will write all the date/time per second, from a start date/time till an end date/time to a file

```
while read line; do
    FIRST_TIMESTAMP="20230109-05:00:01" #this is normally a variable that changes with each $line

    LAST_TIMESTAMP="20230112-07:00:00" #this is normally a variable that changes with each $line

    date=$FIRST_TIMESTAMP
    while [[ $date < $LAST_TIMESTAMP || $date == $LAST_TIMESTAMP ]]; do
        date2=$(echo $date |sed 's/ /-/g' |sed "s/^/'/g" |sed "s/$/', /g")
        echo "$date2" >> "OUTPUTFOLDER/output_LABELS_$line"
        date=$(date -d "$date +1 sec" +"%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
    done
done < external_file
```

However this sometimes needs to run 10 times, and the start date/time and end date/time sometimes lies days apart.
Which makes the script take a long time to write all that data.

Now I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this.

Comment: We miss a sample of your input file `external_file` to be able to help you.

Comment: I don't understand the script: You assign to a variable `line`, but you never actually **use** this variable anywhere. What's the point of it? Also it's not clear where you want to optimize the script. The calculation of `date2` for sure can't be made faster (no need to spawn 4 child processes for this), but I feel that perhaps rethinking the whole algorithm would make more sense.

Comment: Also, since the variable `outputTIMESTAMPS` and `OUTPUTFOLDER` don't change,  and the timestamps file hopefully also doesn't change while the script is running,  you can move the calculation of `FIRST_TIMESTAMP` and `LAST_TIMESTAMP` to ouside of the loops.

Comment: @PerreFrancois:  From what I can see, the content of `external_file` is not really used in this script anywhere. This makes me suspect, that the whole script is not just slow, but most of all buggy.

Comment: @PierreFrançois

I changed some values in the script for privacy reasons, like names and stuff
I changed the values of the start and end time variable so it reflects what is being pulled

and the date2 is being written to different files for each value in external_file (this file just contains names, which I then use to pull the start and end time variables)

Comment: @user1934428 see comment above

Comment: It's fine if you avoid revealing your company secrets here, but if you rename in a way that the resulting program does not make sense anymore, we don't have anything at hand which we can discuss. Alternatively, you could think of providing a small, reproducible example, which exhibits the problem, and which everyone can reproduce.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why would you possibly need to have all the date stamps from thousands of adjacent seconds in a file? If you are trying to then `grep` for any items which contain one of those strings, the sane way to do that is to just extract date stamps and compare them lexically. Like `awk -v first="20230109-05:00: 01" -v last="20230112-07:00:00" '$1 >= first && $1 <= last' file` if `$1` contains the date stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using a separate `date` call for each date. In the next example I added a safety parameter `maxloop`, avoiding loosing resources when the dates are wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
awkdates() {
  maxloop=1000000

  awk \
    -v startdate="${first_timestamp:0:4} ${first_timestamp:4:2} ${first_timestamp:6:2} ${first_timestamp:9:2} ${first_timestamp:12:2} ${first_timestamp:15:2}" \
    -v enddate="${last_timestamp:0:4} ${last_timestamp:4:2} ${last_timestamp:6:2} ${last_timestamp:9:2} ${last_timestamp:12:2} ${last_timestamp:15:2}" \
    -v maxloop="${maxloop}" \
    'BEGIN {
      T1=mktime(startdate);
      T2=mktime(enddate);
      linenr=1;
      while (T1 <= T2) {
         printf("%s\n", strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S",T1));
         T1+=1;
         if (linenr++ > maxloop) break;
      }
   }'
}

mkdir -p OUTPUTFOLDER
while IFS= read -r line; do
  first_timestamp="20230109-05:00:01" #this is normally a variable that changes with each $line
  last_timestamp="20230112-07:00:00" #this is normally a variable that changes with each $line
  awkdates >> "OUTPUTFOLDER/output_LABELS_$line"
done < <(printf "%s\n" "line1" "line2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using epoch time (`+%s` and `@`) with GNU `date` and GNU `seq` to
produce datetimes in ISO 8601 date format:

```sh
begin=$(date -ud '2023-01-12T00:00:00' +%s)
  end=$(date -ud '2023-01-12T00:00:12' +%s)
seq -f "@%.0f" "$begin" 1 "$end" |
date -uf - -Isec
```

```
2023-01-12T00:00:00+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:01+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:02+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:03+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:04+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:05+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:06+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:07+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:08+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:09+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:10+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:11+00:00
2023-01-12T00:00:12+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `macOS/BSD`'s `date` utility instead of the `gnu` one, the equivalent command to parse would be :

```
(bsd)date -uj -f '%FT%T' '2023-01-12T23:34:45' +%s

1673566485
```

...and the reverse process is using `-r` flag instead of `-d`, sans `"@"` prefix :

```
(bsd)date -uj -r  '1673566485' -Iseconds

2023-01-12T23:34:45+00:00

(gnu)date -u  -d '@1673566485' -Iseconds

2023-01-12T23:34:45+00:00
```